# Any Idea something application or system using CBIR (Content Based Image Retrieval)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cbir

i'm sorry, i need your help. i have problem to find unique tecnology (apps, system, or tool)  in topic CBIR. do you have any idea unique apps that can be developed using CBIR? i blind and have nothing idea about CBIR. i mean, i have search idea about CBIR, but its too ordinary, and my teacher asked me to find more attractive idea about CBIR apps. search engine image, apps to identified tourism object, that my idea, any other idea from you?

NB : CBIR Content-based image retrieval (CBIR), also known as query by image content (QBIC) and content-based visual information retrieval (CBVIR) is the application of computer vision techniques to the image retrieval problem, that is, the problem of searching for digital images in large databases (see this survey[1] for a recent scientific overview of the CBIR field). Content-based image retrieval is opposed to traditional concept-based approaches (see Concept-based image indexing).
"Content-based" means that the search analyzes the contents of the image rather than the metadata such as keywords, tags, or descriptions associated with the image. The term "content" in this context might refer to colors, shapes, textures, or any other information that can be derived from the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

for using ordinary methods 
 https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE you may use this library this is a demo site developed

[lire Demo](http://demo-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/liredemo/)

But if you have enough time and enthusiasm you should look **deep learning** topics which is all state of art works on the field done on. Forexample you may look Karpathy's NueralTalk on [github](https://github.com/karpathy/neuraltalk2) `https://github.com/karpathy/neuraltalk2` and the wonderful [demo](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/neuraltalk2/demo.html) page